# multiple canvases are not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I tried to generate multiple canvases on the fly and when I create a new canvas, the previous one disappears.  See here for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianh/5jspv/4/

Here is the javascript code:

```
var circleCount = 0;
function circleRect(rect)
{
    var diameter = Math.sqrt(rect.width*rect.width+rect.height*rect.height);
    var cx = (rect.right + rect.left)/2;
    var cy = (rect.top + rect.bottom)/2;
    var left = Math.floor(cx - diameter/2);
    var top  = Math.floor(cy - diameter/2);
    diameter = Math.floor(diameter);
    var html = "<canvas id='circleCanvas"+circleCount+"' "+
        "width='"+(diameter+2)+"' "+
        "height='"+(diameter+2)+"' "+
        "style='"+
        "position:absolute;"+
        "z-index:0;"+
        "left:"+(left-1)+"px;"+
        "top:"+(top-1)+"px;"+
        //"border:1px solid;"+
        "' />";
    alert(html);
    var container = document.getElementById("circles");
    container.innerHTML += html;

    var c=document.getElementById("circleCanvas"+circleCount);
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(diameter/2+1,diameter/2+1,diameter/2,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ++circleCount;
}

$(".circled").each(function(i, obj) {
    var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
    circleRect(rect);
});
```

Why is only one canvas showing up?

Comment: There are two elements with class `circled`, there are two `canvas` elements in your jsFiddle after your code has run.  What are you expecting to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: I'm expecting that each dynamically generated, uniquely identified canvas to be visible at the end of the execution.  Not just the last one created.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/5jspv/5/

Comment: Ah, ic.  So what I'm doing is each time I'm adding a new one, I'm replacing the old ones with blank ones, where as your example is actually not touching the original canvases?  Is that what's happening?  How does jquerry do that?  Though it is strange since the size of the original ones are not being changed to defaults.  How does that work?

Comment: can somebody tell me why the hell he uses innerHTMl instead of DOM scripting, if he wants JS references to the canvas elements.

Comment: Can someone tell me why @ThorstenArtner'Austria' requires the use of unnecessary words like 'hell' in a question that doesn't require it.  Or why he just doesn't ask me politely?

Comment: sorry but you are not the first person i see that, so i really cant understand the use of innerHTML here, you slow down your code

Comment: The reason why I don't is because I'm ignorant.  Writing in HTML/CSS/JS is not what I do for a living and it's been a while since I've done it.  I usually write in C++/MFC/C#/.NET.  My web development experience is from way back in the late 90s, early 00s.

Comment: I think you're just hitting a problem in trying to do `innerHTML +=` instead of 'proper' DOM manipulation - `innerHTML` has lots of quirks and strange bugs/features.  Also, if you create the `canvas` element like I did you will be able to get the context by simple reference: `var ctx=html[0].getContext("2d");`

Comment: Thanks @robertc, could you either explain or post a link to 'proper' DOM manipulation?

Comment: Provided a bunch of links in my answer, hope they help you get up to speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be more reliable to manipulate the DOM rather than trying to inline things with `innerHTML`.  This code uses [jQuery's DOM manipulation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/):

```
var circleCount = 0;
function circleRect(rect)
{
    var diameter = Math.sqrt(rect.width*rect.width+rect.height*rect.height);
    var cx = (rect.right + rect.left)/2;
    var cy = (rect.top + rect.bottom)/2;
    var left = Math.floor(cx - diameter/2);
    var top  = Math.floor(cy - diameter/2);
    diameter = Math.floor(diameter);
    var html = $("<canvas id='circleCanvas"+circleCount+"' "+
        "width='"+(diameter+2)+"' "+
        "height='"+(diameter+2)+"' "+
        "style='"+
        "position:absolute;"+
        "z-index:0;"+
        "left:"+(left-1)+"px;"+
        "top:"+(top-1)+"px;"+
        "' />");
    $("#circles").append(html);

    var ctx=html[0].getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(diameter/2+1,diameter/2+1,diameter/2,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
    ++circleCount;
}
```

You could also use the standard [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) if you don't really need jQuery.

The [`innerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) has [a number of drawbacks](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/12/38/), although there is nothing specific I can find about not using `+=` with it, the fact that [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.insertAdjacentHTML) exists would seem to indicate that you shouldn't really expect it to work well. (forgot this bit earlier)  In this case, as you correctly surmised in your comment, the `canvas` you've drawn on is replaced by a new one when the assignment to `innerHTML` happens.

Comment: The big advantage of DOM Scripting is having a quick reference by simply creating an element with var reference=document.createElement ("...");
innerHTML is fast but the speed advantage is gone if you set an id and then  connect Javascript with this id, it's like running some rounds around the house and then open door instead of directly go to the door and open it.